# router.beforeEach in laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, authorization, vue.js

(using laravel 5.4 and vue.js 2x)

I use `router.beforeEach()` to handle authorization in my app.
But, my function `router.beforeEach()` is only loading on the moment after login. If I refresh the page the function isn't called again.

Here is my code:

```js
import router from './routes.js';
require('./bootstrap');

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router,
});


router.beforeEach((to,from,next) => {
    if(to.meta.requiresAuth){
        authUser = '';
        const authUser = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('authUser'))
        if(authUser && authUser.access_token){
            next()
        }else{
            next({
                path: '/login',
                query: { redirect: to.fullPath }
            })
        }
    }
    next()
})
```

The full project: https://github.com/jrpikong/wingding

Comment: How do you know it's not being called, did you put a debugger inside the callback?

Comment: yes, I add break point in const authUser = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('authUser'))
if I login script stop , but if I remove break point and login I will redirect to pages dashboard (this good). but if I add break point again and refresh this pages . break point not work .

Comment: Add a breakpoint right before the `if` and check what's the value of `to.meta.requresAuth`

Comment: yeah, just the same, as if the script was not readable

Answer (score 0):

The way to check if the current route requires authentication is documented here: https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/meta.html

Change your `beforeEach` method to this:

```
router.beforeEach((to,from,next) => {
  if(to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth)){
    // do something
  } 
  next();
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help, but now my problem if I press F5 in my browser 
beforeEach doesn't trigger on full page reload. 
 but it does if you navigate between pages via a router-link this is work

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the [Documentation](https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/meta.html),

> All route records matched by a route are exposed on the `$route`
>   object (and also route objects in navigation guards) as the
>   `$route`.matched Array. Therefore, we will need to iterate over
>   `$route.matched` to check for meta fields in route records.

```
router.beforeEach((to,from,next) => {
    if(to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth)){
        authUser = '';
        const authUser = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('authUser'))
        if(authUser && authUser.access_token){
            next()
        }else{
            next({
                path: '/login',
                query: { redirect: to.fullPath }
            })
        }
    }
    next()
})
```

Comment: Be sure to attribute the source of any content you've taken from another website. In this case https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/meta.html

Comment: @thanksd Its the documentation, My intension was to make it easier for you instead reading the whole doc page.

Comment: sure, just be sure to cite the documentation in your answer

Comment: Okay, I am going to mention the doc. Thanks bud.

Comment: thanks for your help @Comrade, but now my problem if I press F5 in my browser 
beforeEach doesn't trigger on full page reload. 
 but it does if you navigate between pages via a router-link this is work

Answer (score 0):

I just switched the position of `router.beforeEach` to be before

```
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
});
```

So, in full, the code looks like this:

```
import router from './routes.js';
require('./bootstrap');

router.beforeEach((to,from,next) => {
  if(to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth)){
    const authUser = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('authUser'))
    if(authUser && authUser.access_token){
      next()
    }else{
      next({
        path: '/login',
        query: { redirect: to.fullPath }
      })
    }
  }
  next()
})

const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
});
```